# MsTest - Speed improvements

Tags: .net, mstest

So i'm stuck with the ugly sister of NUnit. Anyone know of ways to speed this up? It appears to be keen to rebuild EVERYTHING when I just want to re-run the tests (which is not neccessary as I haven't changed any code).

While we're at it does anyone know of a way to turn off the: I WILL WRITE ALL MY RESULTS TO DISK "feature" that slowly fills up one's HDD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both VS 2005 and 2008, the "Deploy" feature found in the .testrunconfig file determines whether the I WILL WRITE ALL MY RESULTS TO DISK feature is turned on or not.

In 2005 you will need to turn it off manually. In VS 2008 it is turned off by default (IIRC).

You may also want to take a look at [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/ploeh/archive/2006/07/13/CleaningAwayTheTestResultsFolder.aspx) that describes how to get rid of the TestResults folder once in a while.

I can't say I've ever experienced that it recompiles everything just to run. In my experience it recompiles just as you would expect the *Build* command to do.

Another thing I've noticed is that the way you organize your test results (i.e. the output) while the tests run can actually impact performance - e.g. if you categorize the test results, it runs slower, apparantly because it's using up CPU cycles updating the list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :)

Well it appears to be spending about 1:30 doing _something_. Mebbe its because i'm using the Resharper plugin. I'd hate to go back to the test list, that's about as helpful as a local who doesn't speak any english and thinks the train station is five miles out to sea. I will check though :).

Comment: Yup, i'm blaming MsTest and it IS the Resharper plugin that is performing the rebuild.